# Favourite proofs with a visualization

Tags: soft-question, visualization

As a fan of 'visual' proofs, I love the book *Visual Complex Analysis* by Tristan Needham.

For example, this picture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pythagoras_algebraic2.svg  leads quickly to Pythagoras's theorem.

I'd like to know which are your favourite examples of a clever visualization that proves or helps the intuition for a proof.

Comment: I've always been fond of the topological proof that all non-constant polynomials have a root, because, even though the rigors of proving the basic homotopy stuff is extreme, it "makes sense."

Comment: You can see my answer in [is this theorem true in optimization theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152722/is-this-theorem-true-in-optimization-theory/152730#152730)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll find many of such "proofs" [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words). The first one is particularly freaky.

I'm personally a fan of using graphs of functions to show their properties. Edgy, right?

Answer (score 3):

Roger B. Nelsen's books  [*Proofs Without Words: Exercises in Visual Thinking, Vol I and II*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857006) are very nice. I particularly like [this](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/46/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=1860) construction of his.

Answer (score 2):

Claudi Alsini and Roger Nelson have published a series of excellent books about what some people call "proofs without words." The most recent of these books is called Icons of Mathematics: An Exploration of Twenty Key Images, was published by MAA in 2011 and has both appealing ideas and mathematics.